# Having an issue getting PHP bindParam to work

Tags: php, database, stored-procedures, pdo

First here is my code:

```
function getRouteZip($dataLib, $route, $date, $dateType) {
    $splib = ObjectFactory::getConnectionParm('splib');
    $stmt = "{Call " . trim($splib) . ".SP_GETROUTEZIP(?,?,?,?,?)}";
    $zip = ' ';

    $pdoStatement = $this->conn->prepare($stmt);
    ObjectFactory::LogMessage("After Prepare Stmt");
    $pdoStatement->bindParam(1, $dataLib, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdoStatement->bindParam(2, $route, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdoStatement->bindParam(3, $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdoStatement->bindParam(4, $dateType, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdoStatement->bindParam(5, $zip, PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 15);
    //$parms = Array($dataLib, $route, $date, $dateType, $zip);

    try {
        $pdoStatement->execute();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        ObjectFactory::LogMessage("Error in Execute: " . $ex->getMessage());
        $zip = 'NOZIP';
    }

    return $zip;
}
```

The code works fine in my development environment running the ODBC driver. However when I move it to my server, which is an IBM i (AS/400) using the PDO IBM driver, the code just stops after the prepare.

The stored procedure that I am trying to call is on the System i as well.

Comment: `errorInfo` function.

Comment: How do you know that code stop after `->prepare()`? Have you verified that `prepare` is successful?